# How to generate a list of categorized list of applications?

Tags: package-management, software-center

When I go to the Ubuntu Software Center and click on Installed, I get a categorized list of all applications. It's something for example like Accessories (Disk, Text editor, ...), Developer tools (Printers, OpenJDK Java, ...), Games Graphics (SignPost, AisleRiot, ...), ...  and so on.

I'd like to have the same list in a textual form in a file. Something like the example above.

Comment: Using apt or aptitude several ways to list various packages. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages  Some other search terms: http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html  details on one application example using zim `apt-cache show zim`

Comment: @oldfred: yes, that would generate a list of all packages, and all intentionally installed applications (with aptitude search '~i!~M'), however, I still would be missing the categories (accessories, ...)

Comment: I do not know where Software Center gets its categories. There also is this: http://superuser.com/questions/585304/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-installed-packages-on-kubuntu-sorted-by-category

Comment: I did find Section and this works:  `aptitude --display-format '%p' search '?Section(games)'`  Or show all apps: `dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} ${Version} ${Section}\n' > filesystem.manifest`

Comment: @oldfred: that's not the same as the list shown by alacarte or classicmenu-indicator. Instead of a list with all games, I get a list with the packages like sgt-puzzles (pkg) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application that gives you all your apps in categorized. The app is called `alacarte`. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

You can find it from dash searching for "main menu" or "alacarte".

[image]

Comment: Corresponding text files are `in ~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: My ~/.local/share/applications is kind of empty (wine stuff, and a little bit more).  Running the alacarte shows much more than that. I wonder where the information above is stored. It shows the same information as classicmenu-indicator, but I don't manage to find the textual information for this one either.